# Filming techniques for Doctor Who during 4th Doctor run

Tags: film-techniques, doctor-who

Does anyone have information on filming techniques during the Doctor Who TV series, or know where such information can be found?

I'm particularly interested in the 4th Doctor era, 1974 - 1981.

Information I'm looking for includes whether they used film (e.g. 35mm), magnetic tape, or other method.  Also information on cameras, audio equipment, etc.

My Google-fu is letting me down, so anything would be appreciated.

Comment: DVD commentaries on Dr. Who frequently include such information, including whether film or video was sued for specific scenes.

Answer (score 1):

[IMDB has this information.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056751/technical)

According the linked page from 1963 to 1985 they used 16mm film for exterior (outdoor) scenes and location shots which I believe means non-studio shots. Video was used for interior shots. [The BBC was known for shooting video indoors and film outdoors.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VideoInsideFilmOutside)